# How do I execute a python file when I receive a specific msg from Mosquitto broker

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, iot, raspberry-pi3, mosquitto

I have made an android app that publishes topics to Cloudmqtt(powered by AWS ) using Mqtt protocol. My raspberrypi has a local Mosquitto broker which is bridged with remote Cloudmqtt. So as soon as I publish a topic via my android app it is received on the raspberrypi console.
Here comes the problem.  As soon as I receive the msg on my raspberrypi console it should execute a python file. How can it be done?

I write this following command to receive the topic

```
mosquitto_sub -h host_name -p port_no -u remote_user_name -P remote_password  -t hello/today/world
```

Now as soon as I receive a msg through the topic `hello/today/world` I have to run a python file that makes decisions according to the msg received from the topic(if the msg received is `on`, the led turns on)

But the main problem is that how can we read the msg and execute the file accordingly?

This morning I saw someone posted a similar question and I took up the challenge to find out the solution but I am not getting any way to do so.

I tried to write in shell but it didn't work

```
c=mosquitto_sub -h host_name -p port_no -u remote_user_name -P remote_password  -t hello/today/world
if ( c == "rushabh welcome to garden assistant" )
then
   GPIO mode 12 out
   GPIO mode 12 1
   GPIO mode 12 0
else
   echo "not matched"
fi
```

Since I want to turn on the led at gpio 12 as soon as I receive `rushabh welcome to garden assistant` from the mosquitto broker

Can we use `$SYS/broker/messages/stored`

Comment: Use the Paho Python MQTT library rather than trying to parse the output of `mosquitto_sub`

Comment: Also the body of your question bares little relation to the title, there is no Python mentioned at all

Comment: But is it possible?, I am loosing my hopes,use of paho library will execute the python file?what about the bridging between cloudmqtt and mosquitto, will it be affected?